# Laptop not starting up

Tags: laptop

I have a Toshiba p755 laptop that, once turned on turns itself off after maybe 3 seconds. If the lid is closed immediately after turning on it'll power up as normal, but once the lid is opened it'll immediately shut down. I've replaced the battery and attempted to replace the cmos battery as well but am having difficulty locating it. Not even sure if that is the problem but I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: We'll need more information, right now you've basically come to a doctor and said, "It hurts. Fix it!" and nothing more.

Comment: I'm not sure what else there is to say. The laptop is a couple of years old, it's had battery problems in the past where the battery wouldn't change charge and this had happened before, except it'd turn off after more time. I used to be able to do a system restore which fixed the problem for a month or so then it would start shutting down again. I did read somewhere about the cmos battery being charged by the laptop battery, but if my battery wasn't working sufficiently then it might not have charged the other battery? I'm just guessing but that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the power button is stuck which force stop after 3 sec holding. The power button might be disabled with lid closed.

Try to press power repeatedly (1sec interval) while the laptop is booting to see if you can achieve more than 3sec.

2nd option would be bad ram but if you are sure the laptop boot with lid close, this is not the problem.

Comment: I tried what you said and didn't see any change in the amount of time the laptop stayed on. Yes I'm certain it can boot up just fine with the lid closed, it's just fine with the lid closed. I can open it to see the home screen and everything,  but then it either goes to immediate black and shuts down or says "windows is shutting down" then shuts down. Think I could use a separate monitor to use my laptop?